How can I use the invokeHttp processor with the Delete method in nifi?
I'm trying to use this processor by getting a token in a previous step, I can get this token, but when performing the invokehttp with the delete method passing this token, an error occurs:

validation of the CSRF token failed

I've tried a few ways: passing the cookie as a header attribute, passing the pure value of the token as a header, but it still hasn't worked Note: I'm trying to make this delete request to a standard SAP S/4HANA API https://api.sap.com/api/API_BUSINESS_PARTNER/resource/Identification




I am assuming other method like GET/POST work fine with the same URL using  CSRF token mechanism. Is that correct?
